# Where can I find more docs about looking glass of gnome-shell?

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-shell

Based on the intrduction at gnome.org , looking glass is really appealing(to me who wants to learn to comstomize my desktop by learning coding)
http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/LookingGlass
But as I searched, not much documetations about looking glass were found.. So where can I learn more about this. Or do I need to learn enough about Gjs to understand the looking glass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know some JavaScript (Gjs), and get familiar with the API you would like to use ( via instrospection).  You can check the [Gjs](https://live.gnome.org/Gjs) wiki page for links.

One way to learn by example is checking the code written for extending GNOME Shell (check [extensions.gnome.org](http://extensions.gnome.org/).

**UPDATE**: The documentation is being updated, and you can find demos with explanations in the [beginners section](http://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/unstable/beginner.js.html.en).  Consider that some are more complete than others because it is a work in progress.

Comment: Now I agree the only way is to read the source code examples, but another quetison: where can I find docs or where can I find help when I failed to understand the code?

Comment: Looking Glass is an access for GNOME shell.  Therefore, you might need to know the internal of GNOME Shell.  You can find links in the wiki page: https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell#Getting_Involved